# Load account information after login Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

When a user logs in, I need to load their information & data. In Parse, I use the `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` method to setup an account. I am not sure how I retrieve that information when they log in. I have tried the following code with no success:

```
class Klikur: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    var loadUser = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
    loadUser.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZEGZ") {(gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil && gameScore != nil {
        println(gameScore)
    } else {
        println(error)
    }
 }
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought that it would pull the row with that ID and give me the information but I guess it is not doing that.

Comment: so if i understand... you want once the **user sign in** into your application if all the information and fields are completed/ correct  you should take them straight to the app

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: And that is what I am trying to use to load their information but it is not working.

Comment: can you show me your code, OR  your want me to give a simple example of **sign up login**

Comment: How about using `PFUser.currentuser()` this will return a PFUser object

Comment: The signup and login functions are already setup, I just don't know how to pass over the information they entered to another view controller if they enter the correct information.

Comment: if you want pass value from one view to another user **prepareForSegue()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse has made this excruciatingly simple. First lets go over some main key points you've subtly discussed:

> When a user logs in I need to load their information & data. In Parse, I use the `signUpInBackgroundWithBlock` method to setup an account. I am not sure how I retrieve that information when they log in.

This is a good start. You are on the right track. There is not much else you need to do once they have successfully signed up. Because you are using that method, you have the object, the object (which contains all their information : username, email, password etc etc). Because you are using a `block`, you have a `callback`, and this is how you retrieve their information. It's all done within the same method, no need to create another instance to provide what's already given. It will look something like this:

```
user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
   (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
   if error == nil {
   // do something if there is an error signing up
   } else {
   // You have a successful log in. Which means you now have a cached user on device
   }
}
```

So how do you get any of the users fields once they sign up? By calling the cached user or `currentUser`. Anything cached means essentially that it's stored on the users device, and it persists, even through app terminations. In this case, its cached as soon as the session is successfully initiated. It will not persist through app deletions and re-installs, but it's cached on your device so you can call it for any circumstance. So in your `signUpInBackgroundBlock` callback or really *anywhere* in a different view controller after they sign up, in order to see the signed in users information you simple need to call `currentUser` so you can retrieve all of it's parameters. Something like this:

```
if error = nil {

} else {
   var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() //This gets the current user where you can get information like
   var userObjectId = currentUser.objectId //returns the current users objectId
   var userUsername = currentUser.username //returns username       
}
```

If you want to get a custom field from your `User` class then you will have to perform a query and you might as well not even bother with the cached version since you're already exhausting an API request to retrieve the custom field values. Say you create a column type String in your `User` class for storing a users phone number. Then you will have to create a query to retrieve that information. Otherwise, you can always use the simplified cached information to display it in any view controller.

Simple user query will look something like this:

```
var query = PFUser.query() //NOTICE there is no classname, this is the proper way to query the User class, no matter what you see elsewhere. 
query.whereKey("username", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser().username)
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
   (user : PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
   if user == nil {
     println("No user with that username")
   } else {
     //retrive your special column data
     let userPhoneNumber = user["PhoneNumberColumnName"] as String
   }         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Milo526 said, if the user is created and logged in,

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()
```

will return that user's data.

However, if your query is for the class User but you set the className to "gameScore" your query will fail the lookup and return an error.

Try:

```
var loadUser = PFQuery(className:"User")
loadUser.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("xWMyZEGZ") {
}
```

While ensuring xWMyZEGZ is an objectId valid in the User table on Parse.

Comment: This should be called when you want to grab the user's info. You can call it before displaying this controller, then pass the user to this controller when it is created so you don't have to wait for the background request to finish after loading but before displaying the info

Comment: One option would be storing a user variable in the appDelegate, then when your signup call saves the new user to the database, also save it to your app delegate. The in the viewDidLoad of this view controller, you can grab the use saved in the appDelegate without having to make another call. However, once again, PFUser.currentUser() will probably handle all this for you simply.